# RDS performance insight average latency metric not showing

Tags: amazon-rds

Does someone know how to visualize "avg latency (ms)/call" and "rows examined/call" on the performance insight dashboard?

I have a MySQL RDS instance with performance insight enabled but metrics like "avg latency (ms)/call" and "rows examined/call" are not being displayed.

I already changed the performance_insight group parameter from 0 to 1 and rebooted the instance with no changes.

I see the "Load by waits":
[image]

[image]

But I don't see "avg latency (ms)/call" and "rows examined/call":
[image]

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. Operations related questions can be asked on the serverfault sister site of SO.

Comment: did you find the solution?